# jquery ajax json data truncates zero values

Tags: html, json, jquery

I'm retrieving a json string as below with jquery ajax and displaying it on a xhtml page

```
{"pID":"T1","avBal":147765035.20,"accBalance":147713417.00}
```

I have the jquery written like this,

```
          $.ajax({

              type : "GET",
              url : '../accData.xhtml',
              dataType : "json",
              async : true,
              cache : false,

              success: function(data) {
                        if(data!=null){
                          $("#accBalance").text(data.accBalance);
                                      $("#avBal").text(data.avBal);
                        }

          },
              error : function() {
          }
         });
```

The issue here is it displays the "avBal" as 147765035.2 and "accBalance" as 147713417 without the zero's all the zero's at the end of the values are truncated automatically. Is it a limitation in jQuery or json or something else is wrong here?

Comment: You may want to pass them as String instead ?

Comment: Since your data come from a file you could modify it to {"pID":"T1","avBal":"147765035.20","accBalance":"147713417.00"}. But here I'm presuming you're the JSON data generator and not a third party

Comment: Place the values between quotes, assuming you're in control of the JSON output...

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not the data generator I cannot change that. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please replace your script as below:

```
$.ajax({

              type : "GET",
              url : '../accData.xhtml',
              dataType : "json",
              async : true,
              cache : false,

              success: function(data) {
                        if(data!=null){
                                //chage is here...
                                 $("#accBalance").text(parseFloat(data.accBalance).toFixed(2));
                                 $("#avBal").text(parseFloat(data.avBal).toFixed(2));
                        }

          },
              error : function() {
          }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery's or JSON's fault, but JavaScript. JavaScript is loosely typed, and 123 & 1.23 are both of the type Number. If the precision is important, treat those values as strings.

Here is a nifty function that will format the values as required:

```
function toFixed(value, precision) {
    var power = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return String(Math.round(value * power) / power);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can Convert this into string inside the ajax success method?